# Would UV-induced-visible-fluorescence indicate the presence of vividly reflecting UV-invisible-light?

Tags: visible-light, wavelength, vision, fluorescence

Some people take amazing photos by using UV-induced-visible-fluorescence(UVIVF). In my understanding, we see in these photos VISIBLE light induced by UV.
https://www.nationalgeographic.com/photography/proof/2018/february/glowing-flowers-ultraviolet-light/

I wonder if materials which generate UVIVF would provide something special vision to watcher who can see UV like honeybees, birds etc. UVIVF is visible for us after all, but are those materials likely to emit UV-invisible-light vividly as well?

(My final purpose of this question is biological theme, but I think the key to understand this is physics. Any hints are welcomed so that I can research further.)

Comment: What are you asking for? How a bee would see what to us appears as a vivid coloured stuff? They should have problem with contrast, similar to us watching something in the visibile against the sun or a lamp. Is one scenario at least. Then it will depends on how that being perceive the visible. Etc.

Comment: UV causing visible fluorescence means that some UV is absorbed, some energy lost, then a visible photon is emitted. If anything, that means that, for a UV-sensitive eyeball there is less UV reflecting off the object since some is being absorbed.

Comment: Thanks!! My expected answer was one like @JonCuster’s comment. You make me realized the meaning “UV-dark areas of flowers” in the article I shared. I understood like this. It means UVIVF part tends to emit less UV reflection, thus that contrast might appeal to UV watchers like honeybees.